# Selenium Webdriver Add In LocalStorage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, local-storage, selenium-chromedriver

I try to add below flag into `LocalStorage` and it doesn't work.

```
localStorage.setItem('ClientRedirectEnabled', 'true');
```

My code below

```
public void FlagIntroduce() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    LocalStorage localStorage = new LocalStorage() {
        @Override
        public String getItem(String s) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> keySet() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setItem(String s, String s1) {
            setItem("ClientRedirectEnabled", "true");
        }

        @Override
        public String removeItem(String s) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {

        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }
    };


}
```

When test starts in chromedriver I'm opening console and Application bookmark. In Local Storage I don't have key and value which I set in setItem

Answer (score 12):

Check example here [LocalStorageTest](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/test/org/openqa/selenium/html5/LocalStorageTest.java)

```
  @Test
  public void testLocalStorageSetAndGetItem() {
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.testurl");

    LocalStorage local = ((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage();    
    
    local.setItem("FOO", "BAR");
 
    local.clear();
   
  }
```

Comment: Updated [LocalStorageTest](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/test/org/openqa/selenium/html5/LocalStorageTest.java)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `JavascriptExecutor` to do the job for you.

If you are using Java as your langugage, following code would help you

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("localStorage.setItem(arguments[0],arguments[1])",key,value));
```

Comment: I input this code with JavascriptExecutor and the same.
`String key = "ClientRedirectEnabled";
        String value = "true";
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("localStorage.setItem(ClientRedirectEnabled,true)",key,value);`

Comment: In the `setItem` let the input arguments be `arguments[0],arguments[1]` Do not change that

Comment: I have below code
`@Override
public void setItem(String key, String value) {
                
setItem("ClientRedirectEnabled", "true");

                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver;
                js.executeScript("localStorage.setItem(arguments[0],arguments[1])",key,value);
            }`

and still the same

Comment: You do not need to create an instance of `LocalStorage` Just write a function without overriding anything. For example `public void setLocalStorage(string key, string value){//impl}`

Comment: I remove Override and currently I have below code
`public void setLocalStorage(String key, String value) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("LocalStorage.setItem(arguments[0],arguments[1])",key,value);
    }`

and still doesn't work

Comment: Can you change the `LocalStorage` case to `localStorage` as I mentioned in my first comment

Comment: Yes but situation is the same. LocalStorage or localStorage and the same.

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: Just wanted to say I stumbled across this solution and it worked for me. I was able to set up the local session on my selenium driver. I did need to remove an extra ")" that I think was a typo.