# How to bypass JWT authentication with Selenium?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, jwt, selenium-chromedriver, integration-testing

So I am trying to make an integration test for my Spring boot rest API with my Vue.js as front-end. The problem happens when I want to go and test something from a page that needs JWT authentication, I cannot seem to get on the page. For the unit tests, I could use the

```
@WithMockUser
```

Annotation, which bypasses the need for authentication to get on pages where this is needed.

I am brand new to this. Here is what I have got so far:

```
package com.example.SeleniumTesting;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FirstMainPageTest {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriver driver3 = new ChromeDriver();

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://localhost:8081");


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver2.manage().window().maximize();
        driver2.get("http://localhost:8081/parties");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver3.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver3.manage().window().maximize();
        driver3.get("http://localhost:8081/parties");
    }

    @Test
    public void loadHomePageTitle(){
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1"));
        element.isDisplayed();
    }


    @Test
    public void loadTheUnauthorizedPage(){
        WebElement element = driver2.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1"));
        element.isDisplayed();
        element.getText();
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void doThis(){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I have tried also using the @WithMockUser in here, but that does not work. Can anyone help me with how I should do this or point me in the right direction (with links to sites that show similar problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how does normal user do the authentication? you'd need to do with Selenium as well, if possible. It is expected that you can't go to a page requiring auth if you don't do the needed auth.

Comment: Authentication mechanism is meant to prevent any users that are not authenticated. This will prevent Selenium access too if you don't authenticate. That is expected, and there really shouldn't be any workarounds or ways to bypass.

Comment: @eis normally the user goes to the login page and fills in the username and password and in the local storage the jwt token gets stored if the credentials are correct. If there is a valid jwt token in the local storage the user can access this page. Should I perform all of this in the test then?

Comment: Yes, you should. You could also put a dummy token in the local storage [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590330/selenium-webdriver-add-in-localstorage), but since for example expiry should be verified by the server, that shouldn't work - so you'd need to do proper login steps.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium tests are part of black box testing patterns, so their purpose is to test the system from outside without having to skip anything that a normal user would do. So I prefer to automate also the login part of the application. The login feature is something you write one time and just use on all tests (e.g Junit @Before).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, makes it much more clear to me!

Answer (score 0):

Authentication mechanism is meant to prevent any users that are not authenticated. This will prevent Selenium access too if you don't authenticate. That is expected, and there really shouldn't be any workarounds or ways to bypass.

As mentioned in the previous answer, you should do all the login steps a regular user would do. It might be that you can reuse login state between tests, which you can use if it is assumed that's what a real user would do, too. However, a fresh login will give you better test results and confidence.