# want to add key and value to an extension of edge browser using selenium webdriver

Tags: webdriver, local-storage, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to load an extension to the edge and provide key, value as headers to that extension(modheader). I was successful in loading the extension to the browser but not able to pass the key, value to the extension.

On searching, I inclined to use localStorage to add key and value, some one please confirm.
Also am not able to perform the task using localstorage. some please help me with the code.
key : IsWebView2
value: true

I have tried with the below code, but no luck. Please verify and suggest.

`executor.executeScript("localStorage.setItem[{'headers':[{'enabled':true,'name':'iswebview2','value':'true'}],'shortTitle':'1','title':'Profile 1','version':2}]");`

Comment: Have you referred [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590330/selenium-webdriver-add-in-localstorage) in this case, if you want to add flag in localstorage via selenium webdrive?

Comment: Thankyou @XudongPeng, this link worked for me in chrome, however edge is giving error as below. I believe there are some settings  need to be modified in edge.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: <unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.

Comment: In this case, have you tried to clear data in localsStorage? Before you redirect to the target Url, tried to excute `window.localStorage.clear(); window.sessionStorage.clear();` and check if this work for you.